# JAX-B enum generation with equal elements

Tags: java, enums, jaxb

I was running into a problem with the generation of an `enum` with JAX-B.
We have a language code in an schema with equal elements separating via the case.
So for example we have an entry with `de` and one with `DE` which results in combination with all the other language codes in an emun with the schema like:

```
/**
 * Afar
 * 
 */
@XmlEnumValue("aa")
VALUE_1("aa"),

/**
 * Afar
 * 
 */
@XmlEnumValue("AA")
VALUE_2("AA"),
```

What is a bit problematic when trying to access a value via the `VALUE_X` naming.
Is there a way to prevent that.
I was expecting the `enum` values like `AA`, `DE` and so on which I know of that they must be unique. What to do in such case where the only difference is the case.

Comment: @davidxxx I generate from xsd schema files I got from a company.

Comment: @dur my colleague used xjc yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is just naming `VALUE_1`, you can fix that by customizing enum member names for, say, lowercase entries:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation=".../myxsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:simpleType[@name='MyLangType']">
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="LOWER_AA" value="aa"/>
            <!-- ... -->
        </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

You may also consider mapping your type directly to `java.util.Locale` using `jaxb:javaType`.

Comment: Thanks lexicore I will try that solution as I get back to company on monday.

Comment: Worked like a charm after writing a program to generate my typesafe bindings as thats a lot of language codes :-)